# Pandas Delete Duplicate Col Names with Specific Col Name

Tags: pandas, duplicates, multiple-columns

I cannot find the answer searching online. Suppose I have a df1 that looks like this with the following column names and I cannot just use a drop on all duplicate col names as most of the online answers suggest.

```
index   year   season   1      2      3     year   season   1      2      3
0       1991   winter   7.1    8.3    9.0   1991   spring   0.5    7.2    1.5
1       1992   winter   4.2    5.1    8.2   1991   spring   2.9    6.2    8.1
```

However, I need the column names to look like this by dropping/deleting subsequent column names of "year" but keeping the duplicate col names of "1,2,3" and 'season' so that the final new df2 looks like this:

```
index   year   season   1      2      3     season   1      2      3
0       1991   winter   7.1    8.3    9.0   spring   0.5    7.2    1.5
1       1992   winter   4.2    5.1    8.2   spring   2.9    6.2    8.1
```

Thank you,

Comment: I'll just comment that dealing with duplicated labels in `pandas` is problematic because it complicates whether functions can return a Series or a DataFrame. `pandas` actively makes it difficult for column labels to be duplicated (typically tries to mangle them to add `.N`) and they do this for a reason.

Comment: yes, if I need to average by columns "1,2,3", how would that work changing the 'season' to "period" col name and the values of the "period" col to 'cold_wx'? Would this give me a "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis error"?

Comment: You can generally get a similar organization with a MultiIndex, which will allow for one level to be duplicated while the full label, i.e. a tuple of `('winter', 1)`, `('spring', 1)` will be un-duplicated. In that case you'd then easily be able to group over either the season or the `1`, `2`, `3`, using a groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case do

```
df.loc[:,(df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).cumcount().eq(0)) | (df.columns!='year')]
Out[188]: 
   index  year  season    1    2    3  season    1    2    3
0      0  1991  winter  7.1  8.3  9.0  spring  0.5  7.2  1.5
1      1  1992  winter  4.2  5.1  8.2  spring  2.9  6.2  8.1
```